# I am trying to display the logged in users tasks in the portal, but program displays 'local variable 'username' referenced before assignment'

Tags: python, function, error-handling, taskmanager

My code so far is:

```
def view_mine():

    with open("tasks.txt", 'r') as g:
        lines = g.readlines()

    user_tasks = []
    for line in lines:
        try:
 
            line = line.split(',')
            if line[1] == username.strip():
                user_tasks.append(line)
        except IndexError:
            continue

    for line in user_tasks:
        username = line[0]
        task = line[1]
        task_description = line[2]
        task_assigned = line[3]
        due_date = line[4]
        task_completion = line[5]
        print("Task username: ", username,
              '\nTask: ', task,
              '\nTask Description: ', task_description,
              '\nDate Assigned: ', task_assigned,
              '\nTask Due Date: ', due_date,
              '\nTask Completed: ', task_completion)
        break
```

I have tried the "global username", but it also brings up an error code where the name 'username' is not defined. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `username` on the `for line in lines:` loop without having created it. Try getting its values with `username = ...`  before calling that loop, so it will be assigned before being used, and your code will work.